# chained then calls the error callback to execute multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
asyncFunction1
    .then(asyncFunction2, errorHandlerFunction)
    .then(Function3, errorHandlerFunction);
```

I am working on a node API application in which I am using the above `then` (using promised-io) sequence. I am having an issue with the chained `then` statements. I have a common `errorHandlerFunction` that is passed an error code which it uses to render an error json response. Something like -

```
var errorHandlerFunction = function(error_code) {
  res.json(message_for_error_code);
};
```

The issue I have is that when `asyncFunction1` function is rejected, it calls the `errorHandlerFunction` method twice. From the logs, the first time around it renders the json response correctly. It gets called a second time (rejected with `undefined`) which throws an error. How do I ensure that the `errorHandlerFunction` exits after running once?

I am guessing I can check for `undefined` in the `errorHandlerFunction` and only render a response for a valid `error_code` (which is not `undefined`). Would this be the right approach? Am I totally overlooking something obvious?

Comment: Uh, `errorHandlerFunction` does only get called twice if the first call did throw an error. Otherwise, *`Function3`* will get called with `undefined` (as your error handler didn't return anything), that sounds more likely to cause the error in your log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your promise chain must break at the first occurrence of error and not going to recover from any error, then instead of error handler at each link of promise chain, you can add a single one in the end.

I am not sure which promise library you are using, if `catch` is available in that you can simply do:

```
asyncFunction1
    .then(asyncFunction2)
    .then(Function3)
    .catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

if not available, then:

```
asyncFunction1
    .then(asyncFunction2)
    .then(Function3)
    .then(null, errorHandlerFunction);
```

Comment: I was assuming that the promise chain would break after an error. i am using promised-io. it does not seem to support catch. https://www.npmjs.com/package/promised-io

Comment: that worked. :) can you please explain how it works?

Comment: @raj, the way promise chain works is, whenever there is an error, it would keep skiping links till it finds the first error handler, so now, you do not need to define errorHandler at each promise link, just adding one in the end would do the trick.

Comment: Suggest caution with promised-io. The documentation says it is Promises/A compliant. Should consider upgrading to promises that are Promises/A+ compliant - eg Bluebird, Q.js, when.js.